# How to index a numerical solution of the 1D wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, python

I am having problems with discretizing the solution to the 1-D Wave equation. The problem lies in defining the size of the matrix needed to hold the solution for $u(x,t)$ for $0\leq x \lt 4 \pi$ and $0 \leq t \leq 16 \pi$. I'll outline my work thus far: It's a little long winded to get to the bit where I'm having problems, so I'll try to be concise:

$$\partial_t^2u(x,t) = c^2\partial_x^2u(x,t) $$

Using substitution to get two first order in time PDE's:

$$
\\ \partial_tu(x,t) = v(x,t)
\\ \partial_t v(x,t) = c^2\partial_x^2u(x,t) 
$$

Adding a parabolic term to give stability to the numeric method gives:

$$
\\ \partial_t u(x,t) = v(x,t) + a\tilde{\partial_x^2}u(x,t)
\\ \partial_t v(x,t) = c^2\partial_x^2u(x,t) + b\tilde{\partial_x^2}v(x,t)
\\ 
$$

Applying the following finite difference operators to the above coupled first order equations,

$$
[\partial_t f(x,t)]_j^n = \frac{f_j^{n+1} - f^n_j}{\Delta t}
\\ [\partial_x^2 f(x,t)]_j^n = \frac{f_{j+1}^{n} - 2f^n_j + f^n_{j-1}}{(\Delta x)^2}
\\ [\tilde{\partial_x^2} f(x,t)]_j^n = \frac{f_{j+1}^{n} - 2f^n_j + f^n_{j-1}}{2\Delta t}
$$

gives our numerical methods to solve u and v:

$$
u_j^{n+1} = u_j^n + \Delta t v_j^n + \frac{a}{2}(u_{j+1}^n - 2u_j^n + u_{j-1}^n)
\\v_j^{n+1} = v_j^n + \frac{\Delta t c^2}{(\Delta x)^2}(u_{j-1}^n - 2u_j^n + u_{j-1}^n) + \frac{b}{2}(v_{j-1}^n - 2v_j^n + v_{j-1}^n)
$$

Initial Conditions are given as: $$u(x,0) = cox(x)$$ and $$\partial_tu(x,0) = v = 0$$

This implies:

$$ u_j^0 = cos(x_0 + j\Delta x), \forall j$$

Finally, boundary conditions are given as:

$$u(x,t) = u(x + 4\pi, t)$$
and
$$v(x,t) = \partial_t(x,t) = \partial_tu(x + 4\pi, t)$$

And now here is where I am banging my head against the wall. I need to figure out the size of the matrix I need for a given time/space grid. Seems easy enoug, right? Just use $\frac{4\pi}{\Delta x}$ columns (plus two for the boundary conditions) and do the same for the time! However, this leads to non integer values, and I need to index my matrix using integers. Further, when I'm all done I have to fish out of my matrix $u(\pi, t)$ and compare it with the actual solution of my PDE. Figuring out which j index holds the value closest to $x=\pi$ using this method is also frustrating me.

What I've done is use the ceiling of $\frac{4\pi}{\Delta x}$ and $\frac{16\pi}{\Delta t}$ to "round" up to the number of rows and columns needed, but this feels very, very bad. I'm looking for an alternative, but can't think of one.

I have coded all of the following in python with the following method (if it is pertinent):

```
Dt = (0.25*DeltaX)/c
# Dt = (16*pi)/3
rows = ceil((16*pi) / Dt)
cols = ceil((4*pi) / DeltaX + 3)

u = zeros((rows, cols))
v = zeros((rows, cols))

for j in range(cols):
    u[0][j] = cos(-DeltaX + j*DeltaX)
    v[0][j] = 0

for i in range(1, rows):
    for j in range(1, cols-1):

        # u(x,t): fill row (time) i of grid space for columns (space) j
        u[i][j] = u[i-1][j] + Dt*(v[i-1][j]) + (a/2)*(u[i-1][j+1] - 2*u[i-1][j] + u[i-1][j-1])

        # v(x,t): fill row (time) i of grid space for columns (space) j
        v[i][j] = v[i-1][j] + ((Dt*pow(c, 2))/pow(DeltaX, 2))*(u[i-1][j+1] - 2*u[i-1][j] + u[i-1][j-1])
        + (b/2)*(v[i-1][j+1] - 2*v[i-1][j] + v[i-1][j-1])

    u = apply_bcs(u, DeltaX, i)
    v = apply_bcs(v, DeltaX, i)

 print(u)
```

Comment: As you increase the number of nodes, your solution will become more accurate. I cannot understand why making your solution more accurate feels bad for you?

Comment: It doesn't. I asked for a better way to find the number of rows and columns needed to hold a solution set for a given time and space grid. I didn't say anything about decreasing the grid spacing being a problem.

Comment: What I meant was like choosing $\Delta x$ and $\Delta t$ is arbitrary, one may say the number of rows is equal to the length of an array that starts from $0$ to $4\pi$ with steps of an arbitrary $\Delta x$. Likewise for `t`.

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar Ok, true... I don't have to evaluate the function at exactly $4\pi$, since it's a "strictly less than"... That makes sense! What about when I have to compare the solution $u(\pi, t) = -cos(t)$ to my numerical solution? $\pi$ won't necessarily fall on one of my multiples of $\Delta x$.

Comment: You can absolutely evaluate your function at exactly $4\pi$ too. 

Let me explain: if $\Delta x=\dfrac{(4\pi-0)}{(m+2)-1}$ where $m$ is an arbitrary number of internal nodes, then by choosing any arbitrary $m$ you can find $\Delta x$.

Comment: Insert $m=1$ as an example. (i.e. 1 internal node, 2 boundary nodes) then $x=[0,2\pi,4\pi]$

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. I do see how using some integers divisors yields nice even results for my nodes... However, what I must use as $\Delta x$ is dictated to me and isn't so pretty. But you definitely answered my question about doing the rows and columns more simply. Thanks you.

Comment: It seems unfair and unnecessary for the elements to be dictated, in computational problems. Because as long as you can decrease the element size, your solution is more accurate. However, if you have to do so, I think you need the rounding up thing you assumed first. But keep in mind that your solution was not wrong and the number of rows with the mentioned $\Delta x$ could not be an integer at all. You're welcome pal.